# Why I Fail to AJAX post in Nodejs-msnodesqlv8 app?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, ajax, post, connection

I am using msnodesqlv8 package in Nodejs to connect to a SQL server database. Of course I installed the package and I already had a SQL database on a server. I used the required options for connection and succeeeded in retrieving records.
To start with, My app.post code is:

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const sql = require('msnodesqlv8');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const connString="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myserver;Database=myDB;Uid=muUid;Pwd=myPwd;" 


app.post('/persons',  (req, res) => {
   const formData = req.body;
    try {
        console.log("Posting"); 
        // Create a new person record in the database
        const query=`INSERT INTO persons (name, age, gender) VALUES (${formData.name}, ${  
        formData.age}, ${formData.gender})`;
        console.log(`${formData.name}, ${formData.age}, ${formData.gender} will be written.`);
        sql.query(connString, query,(err,rows)=>{
        
        res.send(rows);
    });  
      
    } catch (err) {
      
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
```

HTML code:

```
<form id="newRecform"> 
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">      
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="age">Age:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="age" id="age" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
                      <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender" required>
                        <option value="">-- Select gender --</option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                      </select>
                    </div> 
                 </div>   
                <br><br><br>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm col-md-2" style="border-radius: 3px;" type="submit">Add Patient</button>
                </form>`
```

AJAX post code:

```
$("#newRecform").on("submit", function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://localhost:5001/persons',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: $(this).serialize() ,
                  success: function (data) {
                      alert('New Record added successfully!')
                  }
                  , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                      alert('Error ' + textStatus + ', err ' + err)
                  }
              });
        });
```

When I submit the form, it never executes the app.post. Even the 'console.log' command does not work inside the post code

Comment: Aside... `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` has not seen any feature updates since SQL Server 2012 and, finally, Microsoft has removed it completely from current versions of SQL Server and SSMS. Have you considered using the more modern, and currently supported, `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` or `ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server` instead?

Comment: Aside... Be aware that directly inserting tainted user input into your SQL query like that is a bad security practice known as SQL Injection. Try reading up on [User Binding of Parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8#user-content-user-binding-of-parameters) and implementing it, otherwise you could end up with [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) on your hands.

Comment: Is the Express app actually listening on http://localhost:5001? Instead of `url: 'http://localhost:5001/persons'` have you tried simply `url: '/persons'`?

Comment: It is a bit faster using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server! @AlwaysLearning.. I changed 'url' to '/persons' and I changed  the sql query into a parameterized  one (?, ?, ...), however, invoking the post request was unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
modify app.post code to:

```
app.post('/patients',  (req, res) => {
    const formData = req.body;
    const query = 'INSERT INTO persons(name, age, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    const params = [`${formData.name}`, `${formData.age}`, `${formData.gender}`];
    sql.query(connString, query, params, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Rows affected:', rows);
    }
    });
```